# VBA Create search results in userform listbox

Tags: excel, vba, userform, listboxitem

I am trying to create a userform that displays results in a listbox if textbox1 and textbox2's value matches cell value

Textbox1 will = cell value I1
Textbox2 value will be yes, no, maybe (whatever is in cell H1)

the listbox results will then return i.e Column A Data Mon, Tues, etc and all the Yes results in column below cell c3, I can only return the value in c3

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myString

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("I1").Select
myString = Range("I1")

UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = myString

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("H1").Select
myString = Range("H1")

UserForm1.TextBox2.Text = myString

Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = ws.Range("B3:G3")
Set fnd = rng.Find(TextBox1)
If fnd Is Nothing Then MsgBox TextBox1 & " not found": Exit Sub
Set first = fnd
With ListBox1
    .Clear
    .AddItem fnd.Offset(, 0)
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = fnd.Offset(, -1)
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = fnd.Offset(, 1)


    Do
        Set fnd = rng.FindNext(fnd)
        If fnd.Address = first.Address Then Exit Do
            .AddItem fnd.Offset(, 0)
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = fnd.Offset(, -1)
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = fnd.Offset(, 1)

    Loop
    End With
    End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Simplified example call**

Assuming your cell value in `H1` is a text string and no data, I show you a simplified approach assigning the data block to a 2-dimensional (1-based) array to facilitate search. Note that a listbox'es `.List` property has to be referenced by zero-based indices.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Prefill textboxes with choice from sheet
If Me.TextBox1.Text = vbNullString Then Me.TextBox1.Text = Sheet1.Range("I1")
If Me.TextBox2.Text = vbNullString Then Me.TextBox2.Text = Sheet1.Range("H1")

'Find column caption (e.g. "1-3")
Dim ws    As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim fnd   As Range
Set fnd = ws.Range("B3:G3").Find(TextBox1)
If fnd Is Nothing Then MsgBox TextBox1 & " not found": Exit Sub

With ListBox1
    .Clear
    .ColumnCount = 2            ' (if not defined yet in UserForm_Layout or Initialize)
    'write data to 2-dimensional 1-based array
    Dim myData As Variant
    myData = ws.Range("A4:G8")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(myData)          ' loop through rows in data array
        If LCase(myData(i, fnd.Column)) = LCase(TextBox2) Then ' check Yes|No|Maybe
            .AddItem myData(i, 1)        ' add item row to list & weekday as first value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = myData(i, fnd.Column)
        End If
    Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: Example searching "1-2" and "Yes"]

Comment: @Andy - posted a late answer to your userform listbox issue demonstrating an array approach - would appreciate feedback :-)